# Appcelerator, Android crashes with Ti.Map module on some devices

Tags: android, dictionary, crash, appcelerator

i'm currently using appcelerator Titanium to develop a multiplatform app using Alloy framework and Ti.MAP module. 
It appears that on some devices, this MapView seems to create a bug as the app crashes "app stopped to work" as soon as the app loads the map. 
For example, its working fine on a Nexus 6, and does not work on a samsung galaxy S6.
If i comment my line // $.map.add(mapview) , the app works well on both devices. but if i uncomment this line, the app crashes on galaxy S6 without any error message.

Any idea on this point ?

Best regards,

Quentin

EDIT : the problem seems to come from the annoations and not from the map itself. If i comment my line //map.addAnnotation(temp); its working well again.

This is a code example of an annotation i use :

```
if(Ti.Platform.name === 'android'){
        rightview = Ti.UI.createView({
            width:'50',
            height:'50',
            backgroundColor:'#17BDA1',
        }); 
        leftview = Ti.UI.createView({
            height:'10',
            backgroundColor:'white'
        });
        handi = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:imghandi,
            width:'20',
            left:'5'
        });
        lift = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:imglift,
            width:'20',
            left:'30'
        });
        moto = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:imgmoto,
            width:'20',
            left:'55'
        }); 
    }   

    leftview.add(handi); 
    leftview.add(lift);
    leftview.add(moto); 

    var temp = MapModule.createAnnotation({
        title:title,
        subtitle:subtitle,
        longitude:longitude,
        latitude:latitude,
        pincolor: pincolor,
        leftView : leftview,
        rightView : rightview,
        parking:parking,
        image: '/images/logos/logo_carte.png'
    });
    mapview.addAnnotation(temp);
```

parking: parking is an object i need to use on my click event listener.

EDIT 2 : the pb seems to come from the image. if i comment the //image : ... line on the annotation object description, it works fine..

Comment: Are you adding any data (annotations) on the map? Can you provide some of your code so we can see how the map is implemented?

Comment: Yes you right, the problem seems to be linked to the annotations i'm adding to the map. if i comment my line //map.addAnnotation(temp); its working well. im adding a code example on my question ;)